# How to delete testnet blockchain files on Mac to save some space?

Tags: mining

I'm new for ethereum. I downloaded the wallet. I found out I'm on test net. I moved to main now. I would like to delete blockchain file of test-net if it is different then main?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the mainnet data will be different from the testnet and you will have to redownload the data. If you are using mist, then you can find the data directory at `~/Library/Ethereum` on mac.
Your data is stored in chaindata folder which is `~/Library/Ethereum/chaindata`. So you can delete this to remove the data.

Comment: Why do we need testnet at all? For developers ?

Comment: Yes for developers, if you want to test some application before deploying it on the mainnet.